# How do you handle searching and reports on contributions with line items from Webform CiviCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm, line-items

Webform CiviCRM for Drupal 7 allows one to set multiple line items with different financial types for one contribution. In this case, a charitable donation and a non-charitable event ticket.

If I set the charitable donation as the primary contribution and the event ticket as the additional line item, this works fine to set the tax receipt correctly for only the amount of the charitable donation (if the non-charitable event ticket is primary, you can't send a tax receipt).

What I don't understand is how to handle contribution searches or reports in this case. If I want to know how much we received in donations last year, I would normally use a search or a report. However, I believe these would both now be incorrect as they would show a $X+Y donation, when I actually have a $X donation and a $Y event ticket. Does this mean I can only use line item reports and can't use regular contribution reports or contribution searches if I have contributions generated in this way?

Is there a way to create two separate contributions instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Extended Report extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport)

It offers new reports like Extended Report - Price Set Line Items

Comment: We use Webforms for our contribution forms. And we use the Extended Reports mentioned in petednz answer. When we create an event registration webform we have the event fee and the contribution both use Line Items. If you filter Extended Report - Price Set Line Items by "Contribution" Financial Type and by "Line Item" Financial Type, you can pull just the contribution portion that was given.

Comment:  Roger that answer (I needed more char)!

Comment: Thanks, sounds like this is the answer. We definitely can find line items in Extended Reports, but it's a big downgrade in usability not to be able to find contributions of a certain financial type (i.e. donations) via advanced search and not to be able easily see in a contact record when a contact has donated versus paid for an event or something else. So we'll stick with contributions that only contain line items of one financial type for now.

Comment: Here is our work around. We have Financial Types that are Master Types. Ie Donation, Event Fees, Tuition. Then we have Financial Types that we treat as sub types. Ie Under Donation is General Fund, Capital Campaign, Scholarship.       
                                                                                                                             
 When you create the Price Set, for Donate we have the Price Set financial type Donation, the price fields are all General Fund, Capital Campaign (Line Items).

Comment: Then in webform, build in your event fee.            For the Contribution tab you add the Line Item (General Fund) . I do not include the "Contibution Amount" field. Now you can pull reports as I describe above.   Our Master Financial Type reports can use the Contribution Reports. Our sub financial types we need to use the Extended Reports